# Filtering event by custom audience doesn't work

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am having a problem with filtering event by custom audience.

Here is what I did:

1. I have created a custom event with name, "test_audience_event" .

When choosing date = "5.7.2016 - 5.7.2016", I can see this custom events as you can see in the below picture:
[image]

2. I've created audience with name "has_test_audience_event", users who have at least one "test_audience_event" event.
   as you can see in the below picture:
   [image]
3. but now in events console when I set "has_test_audience_event" audience I got zero events. as you can see in the below picture:
   [image]

Why I got zero events? At least I should got the events of "test_audience_event"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audience membership evaluation is *prospective*, not *retrospective*.  The [Help Center](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) documentation phrases it this way

> Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified
>   criteria from that point onward.

Once more test_audience_events are logged, you should see the Audience user count grow.